# How to Redirect a login request to an external domain using PHP (Using Laravel 4)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, request

I have two webs (Client side and Admin side) but are independent, I mean are in different domains but both using the same DB. I want to allow the Admins to login from Client side but once I recognize that isn't a normal user I want to redirect the login request to the other web and parse everything from the Admin side, just if I was trying to login from the admin web.

```
$credentials = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    $message = "Wrong Data";

    try {
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            if(Auth::user()->role_id < 4) {
                $url = 'http://externaldomain.info/login';
                $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$credentials);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                $response = curl_exec ($ch);

                curl_close ($ch);
                return $response;
            }
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    } catch( \Toddish\Verify\UserNotFoundException $e ) {
        $message = _("User not found");
    } catch( \Toddish\Verify\UserUnverifiedException $e ) {
        $message = _("User not found");
    } catch( \Toddish\Verify\UserDisabledException $e ) {
        $message = _("User disabled");
    }
```

Instead of the dashboard I get the login screen, I checked it with fiddler and didn't see any post request to the external domain, I just saw the login page request(GET).

EDIT

```
$credentials = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    $message = "Wrong Data";

    try {
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            if(Auth::user()->role_id < 4) {
                $url = 'http://externaldomain.info/login';
                $html = new \Htmldom($url);
                $token = "";
                foreach($html->find('input') as $element) {
                    if($element->name == "_token") {
                        $token = $element->value;
                    }
                }
                $credentials['_token'] = $token;
                $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$credentials);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                $response = curl_exec ($ch);

                curl_close ($ch);
                return $response;
            }
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    } catch( \Toddish\Verify\UserNotFoundException $e ) {
        $message = _("User not found");
    } catch( \Toddish\Verify\UserUnverifiedException $e ) {
        $message = _("User not found");
    } catch( \Toddish\Verify\UserDisabledException $e ) {
        $message = _("User disabled");
    }
```

I'm using `"yangqi/htmldom": "dev-master"` to get the "_token", but I can't see the Request in fiddler, it keeps redirecting me to the login page instead of the dashboard.

Comment: So you're saying the cURL request is not being triggered?

Comment: I can't see the request being triggered in fiddler

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you forgot to add "_token" and "remember" fields.

The post you need to make should contain those for default login panel:

```
_token  JB6nC85wLkFQtTglpiuoWk06YxI3Jx3no0xVQx0K
email   admin@blabala.com
password    123456
remember    on
```

Token is created by Laravel automatically for protecting your application from [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks.

You have two ways, first make request to your login page scrap the token. Then make a second request for post with that token.

Second you can [disable the token](http://www.camroncade.com/disable-csrf-for-specific-routes-laravel-5/) for login page.

Ok, after your edit missing thing to do adding COOKIEJAR in curl request. Your current request is working like a browser with cookies disabled.

```
            $url = 'http://externaldomain.info/login';

            $file = "cookiefile.txt";
            $fp = @fopen($file, "x");
            if($fp)
            fclose($fp);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $response_token = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

            $html = new \Htmldom();

            // Load HTML from a string
            $html->load($response_token);

            $token = "";
            foreach($html->find('input') as $element) {
                if($element->name == "_token") {
                    $token = $element->value;
                }
            }


            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$credentials);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $response = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

BTW, your first request to page should also need to use same cookie file. I suggest you to use curl for making the first request too.

Comment: Thanks I didn't have that in mind, I'm getting the "_token" and doing the request, I don't need the remember thing, but I can't see the request in fiddler, It keeps redirecting me to the login page.. take a look at the "EDIT".

Comment: @Syxkno ok i have added cookiejar for both of your requests.